# How to divide a complex polygon into simple polygon using boost?

Tags: algorithm, boost

I am looking for transforming a complex polygon(self intersecting polygon) into simple convex polygon.

```
-----------------------------
 -                        -               
   -                    -
     -                -
       -            -
         -        -
           -    -
             -
           -    -
         -        -
       -            -
     -               -
    -                 -
   -                   -
   ----------------------
```

The above picture should result in two polygon(triangle).

I am working on boost library and looking for a solution using boost library.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume your initial polygon is ...xa,xb,....,xc,xd,.... (where xi are vertices), and edges xa,xb and xc,xd intersect. Then you have two polygons: ....xa,xe,xd,... and xe,xb,...,xd.

Now if two polygons intersect they have to intersect at two places (or even number of places). If two polygons ....xa,xb,...xc,xd,....  and  ...xe,xf,....xg,xh,... intersect at (xa,xb) (xe,xf) and (xc,xd) (xg,xh) you have two sets of new polygons with two new vertices xi and xj (I will let you figure out the exact nature of those polygons).

Then there are algorithms to figure out the list of pairs of line segments that intersect.

Combine these three pieces and you get your algorithm.